# Is there a more elegant/functional way to calculate an average price?

Tags: kdb

I've come across this task a few times and I believe it's quite common in trading: calculate volume-weighted average price.

I have this table the represents executions of price and qty:

```
t:([] qty:500j, 1400j, 1700j, 600j, 1500j, 1500j, 1200j, 1300j, 1600j, 1700j; price:9.96 9.94 10.02 9.91 9.93 10.03 10.09 9.97 9.98 10.08)
```

The way I usually calculate the average price is this:

```
(sum exec qty*price from t)%(sum exec qty from t)
```

Is there a more functional way? Maybe with adverbs?

Answer (score 6):

Use '[wavg](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/avg/#wavg)' function:

```
 q)select qty wavg price from t
```

Comment: Didn't know that function exists. Thanks. Always impressive to see how powerful q is and lets you express what you want to express in with so little code.

Answer (score 3):

If using an un-keyed table:

```
t[`qty]wavg t[`price]
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use `select qty wavg price from t`, however replacing `select` with `exec` will return an atomic value rather than a table which might suit your need better

```
exec qty wavg price from t
```

wavg calculated the average price weighted by qty.